# Request timed out error after switch to new server

Tags: asp.net, webforms, windows-server-2019

After upgrading from Windows Server 2012 R2 to Windows Server 2019, my ASP.net WebForms app began throwing more frequent "Request timed out." errors. A typical day would see 0-5 such errors, but now it is about 100 errors. There has been no change to the code and the new server has the same specs as the old server. Stack trace is below. This happens across a small subset of pages without any particular unifying feature. Page timeout and max allowed content length are the same on this server as the previous, as are as many of the config settings I can think to check. Have I missed a configuration setting somewhere?

```
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```